# R Error: "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, object, closures, subset

I am receiving the following message when I run my code. I am attempting to perform a mediation analysis.

**"Error in new$meddepression : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"**.

I am very new to programming and to R. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Below is my code.

```
doEffectDecomp = function(d)
{
  d$actlim2Temp=d$actlim2
  mdepression = glm(depression ~ actlim2Temp, family=binomial(), data=d)

  d1 = d2 = d
  d1$meddepression = d1$actlim2
  d2$meddepression = !d2$actlim2
  newd = rbind(d1,d2)

  newd$actlim2Temp = newd$actlim2
  w = predict(mdepression, newdata = newd, type='response')
  direct = ifelse(newd$depression, w, 1-w)

  newd$actlim2Temp <-  new$meddepression
  w = predict(mdepression, newdata = newd, type='response')
  indirect = ifelse(newd$depression, w, 1-w)
  newd$Wdepression = indirect/direct

  newd$W = newd$Wdepression
  cox=coxph(Surv(days_in_study, censor) ~ meddepression + actlim2, weight=W, 
 data=newd)

  TE=exp(sum(coef(cox)[c('actlim2', 'meddepression')]))
  DE=exp(unname(coef(cox)['actlim2']))
  IE=exp(sum(coef(cox)[c('meddepression')]))

  PM = log(IE)/log(TE)

  return(c(exp(coef(cox)), TE=TE, DE=DE, IE=IE, PM=PM))
}

doEffectDecomp(d)
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Simran

Comment: you should consider documenting / commenting on your code. This is kinda hard to read / follow.

Comment: I suspect a typo of a missing "d"   As well as failure to provide 'sessionInfo()'. The error message says the interpreter tried to get an S4 object the it thought would be a function.

Comment: You are trying to subset the `new` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your input. it turns out I was missing a "d" as you suspected 42-. This has been a lifesaver, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in the code, I was missing a "d".  `new$meddepression` should have read `newd$meddepression`.

Thank you very much for all your input, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Typo was my problem also.